# Backbone - how our model knows if server sends "Error Message" using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, backbone.js, synchronization

I have a model,having url property.
When i save the model using "Save" method, it is sending request to the server.
If the communication is success, the success() method is triggering and if communictaion is failed, "error" function is being triggered.
But, what if there is no communication problem but when the server sends a "failed message" due to some server validations or for other reasons ?
As , due to server side validations(or others),the model not saved in server.
So, it shouldnot be saved in backbone model also.
What should i do to tell the model not to save when the server sends "Error updating database" and tell it to save when i receive "Successfully updated"
I am sending the below response  from server :

```
    $this->response(
        array(
             'model'=>$model,
             'status'=>$status,
             'metamodel'=>array(),
             'message'=>$msg  (either success or fail)(my custom message)
            )
          );
```

in the client side,i am saving like this.

```
        model.save(attr{
          success:(model,res)->
            // to do when communication success
          error:(model,res)->
            //to do when communication fails
         })
```

So, how can i check based on the message or the status  whether server succeeded or not ?
And,how can i tel model not to save or revert the changes when server says "no"(NOT INTERNAL SERVER ERROR, my custom error bcoz of validations or other reasons)

Also, how can i use Backbone.Sync method ( practical example related to my code,please)
and what does it do? (plz mention clearly whether comunication problem or custom error mesage or internal server error)

I can access "status" and "message" in the "success" method , but how can i use them to revert changes to model .
Thanks

Comment: If your backend is set up to handle REST requests, you don't need to change the sync method of backbone. It should work out of the box. To handle errors, you should send the correct HTTP Code on error instead of the default 200. If you do that it should call the error handler. I've never used CodeIgniter, but I'm sure there is way to change to the http code in the response.

Comment: how can i send HTTP code on error ?u mean status message ?

Comment: Here is a link to what the Backbone manual says: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-save. Read the part on save. It says to return a "non-200 HTTP response code" to invoke the erro code.

Comment: Again, I've never used CodeIgniter, but looking through their manual, you could set the HTTP response using $this->output->set_status_header(code, 'text'); http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html

Comment: ya,i want to use "wait:true", means i want to wait for the server to aknowledge before commiting changes to model at front end, but how could i implement that, can u please tell me ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time for a complete answer right now. Nor do I know the exact answer. I may try later tonight, but hopefully someone will have answered your question by then. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overwrite the `parse(response)` method on the model and check for an error flag. 
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse